# Content form sending blank email

Tags: php

I created a contact form. When I fill everything and click submit and then go see my email on gmail. All the section are blank.
Example of what I receive :

```
Name:
Email:
Subject:
Message:
```

Here is my html code :

```
        <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="Emailaddress" id="Emailaddress" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <textarea name="Message" id="Message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is my php code :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$FirstName = trim(stripslashes($_POST['FirstName']));
echo "Found Firstname: " . $FirstName;
$LastName = trim(stripslashes($_POST['LastName'])); 
echo "Found LastName: " . $LastName;
$Emailaddress = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Emailaddress'])); 
echo "Found Emailaddress: " . $Emailaddress;
$subject = 'This is the subject';
echo "Found subject: " . $subject;  
$Message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));
echo "Message: " . $Message;    

$email_from = $Emailaddress;
$email_to = 'karolburatynski@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $FirstName . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $Emailaddress . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $Message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

Comment: First thing to do is remove the error suppression `@` on your mail() call.

Comment: check `var_dump($_POST)`. If there are no values in it, check "network" panel in Chrome Developer Tools (or sth like that). If you see values in DevTools and can't see them in POST, check if $_POST not getting overwritten somewhere in your code.

Comment: I checked the code at my side on localhost, var_dump and $status both are not showing any problem regarding blank data. I think the problem is with @mail. As @j08691 suggested you to try by removing `@` from mail method.

Answer (score 2):

Look for your javascript that handle the contact-form and replace this line:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
```

for this one:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(), function(data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You coding have problem here is the solution:

```
<?php
//print_r($_POST); die; 
//uncomment it if you would liketo do debug

    $FirstName = trim(stripslashes($_POST['FirstName']));
    $LastName = trim(stripslashes($_POST['LastName'])); 
    $Emailaddress = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Emailaddress'])); 
    $subject = 'This is the subject';
    $Message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));


    $email_from = $Emailaddress;
    $email_to = 'karolburatynski@gmail.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $FirstName . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $Emailaddress . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $Message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
  ob_end_flush();

   header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );
    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

You shouldn't start with  header('Content-type: application/json');. as in this case the whole page is treated as json. So its not working.

Comment: Your solution will output "headers already sent" warning, because of  `echo` before `header`. Or, if global output buffering is on, it will act exactly the same as if the `header` were at first line.

Comment: yap you are write. i do not know why you need to print text & return json as well in one place?

Comment: I guess `echo` is just for debugging - response generated like that wouldn't be parsable as json. But the problem is somewhere else :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies , I really appriciate. I change the code but it s still sending me blank email . That s what i receive  :  Name:

Email:

Subject: Client

Message:

Comment: first try with print_r($_POST); and check whether there any value available or not. If no value avilable then you have problem in your form. again if you still facing this problem paste your code in pastebin & give it to me i will solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look for your javascript that handle the contact-form and replace this line:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
```

For this one:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(), function(data) {
```

"change this lines then mailer will Work