# PHP form posting blank values

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a simple submission form in my index.html file that will send an email with the values, but they are always blank after grabbing them with $_POST. Here is my form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="/rtp/php/submit.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">
                            Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="theName" class="form-control" id="theName" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">
                            Email Address</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="email" name="theEmail" class="form-control" id="theEmail" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject">
                            Subject</label>
                        <select id="subject" name="theSubject" id="theSubject" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                            <option value="service">Criminal Defense</option>
                            <option value="service">Personal Injury</option>
                            <option value="service">Consitutional Law</option>
                            <option value="service">Immigration</option>
                            <option value="suggestion">General Inquiry</option>
                            <option value="suggestion">Scholarship</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">
                            Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" name="theMessage" id="theMessage" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                            placeholder="What can we help you with?"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                        Send Message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

And here is my submission script:

```
 <?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

// Set destination
$email_to = "bali*****l.com";
$email_from = "br******offee";
$email_subject = "Rai*******rship";

// Grab fields
$name = isset($_POST["theName"]) ? $_POST['theName'] : 'Name Not set';
$email = isset($_POST['theEmail']) ? $_POST['theEmail'] : 'Email not set';
$subject = isset($_POST['theSubject']) ? $_POST['theSubject'] : 'subject not set';
$message = isset($_POST['theMessage']) ? $_POST['theMessage'] : 'message not set:(';

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


// Clean up
function clean_string($string) {

$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}

// Set string
$email_message .= $name."\n";
$email_message .= $email."\n";
$email_message .= $subject."\n";
$email_message .= $message."\n";


$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    print("The message -> $email_message");

?> 

Congratulations, you are entered to win! You should hear from us shortly :)
```

All variables end up blank. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to figure this out for hours. I do not understand why the POST function is not grabbing the values and passing them through.

Comment: What does `var_dump($POST);` show?

Comment: Another very recent post about the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673668/content-form-sending-blank-email Got the suggestion, "check var_dump($_POST). If there are no values in it, check "network" panel in Chrome Developer Tools (or sth like that). If you see values in DevTools and can't see them in POST, check if $_POST not getting overwritten somewhere in your code"

Comment: Your `enctype` is incorrect. Try setting it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or removing it (so it defaults to that encoding type) or setting it to `multipart/form-data`. Otherwise you will need to manually process the request body and parse he data into something usable yourself.

Comment: Just remove `enctype="text/plain"`

Comment: Thanks for the help - ended up being enctype like many suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that you can just remove the enctype tag altogether -- I've never needed to include that on a form sent via Post.

As an additional aside, though:

Do you mean that the variables are blank if the web form is left blank?

When a form is submitted via POST and a field is empty, it is sent as an empty string.

So, for example, if you left the entire form blank then $_POST['theName'] would be sent as "".

ISSET will return true on a blank string -- so, all of your ISSET tests are returning true.

Try !empty instead.  For example:

```
$name = !empty($_POST['theName']) ? $_POST['theName'] : 'No Name Set';
```

If it is returning blanks even when something is entered on the form please clarify.

Also, in your `<select><option>` tags, POST is going to send the value of whatever is selected.  You currently have multiple Options with the same value.  It does NOT send what is between the `<option`> tag (in other words, whether they choose "Criminal Defense" or "Personal Injury" $_POST['theSubject'] will be "service" for both.

Answer (score 2):

remove *enctype="text/plain"* from form tag and check.